# CSS styles are not being applied to React file

Tags: css, reactjs

I am working on a web based project. All code is executed but the styles are not being applied to files. Below is code of my react file. I also added my css file below it.

I tried using .sass extension which is also not working.

Can anyone help me with it? How do I apply styles?

```
import "./App.css";
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function App(){ 
 const [searchVal,setSearchVal]=useState('');
    //getting values from DB

    return <div>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Search College" onChange={event =>{setSearchVal(event.target.value)}}></input>
     {collegeList.filter((val)=>{
         if(searchVal==""){
             return val;
         }else if (val.Name_of_College.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())){
             return val;
         }
     }).map((val)=>{
        return <div className="clgListDiv" > <p>
          College Name: {val.Name_of_College} <br></br>
          </p>
          </div>
          })}
   </div> 
}
export default App;
```

This is the css file

```
.App{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.APP input{
    margin-top: 20px;
    width:350px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: check your classnames please.. I can't see any "App" or "APP" classname in your component

Comment: It doesn't appear any React/JSX code uses any CSS from your shared snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it doesn't work because you didn't add className attribute in JSX code in first div and maybe you should rename .APP input to .App input in your CSS file as you also want same styling in input tag also.

```
 import "./App.css";
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
    import Axios from "axios";
function App(){ 
 const [searchVal,setSearchVal]=useState('');
    //getting values from DB

    return <div className='App'>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Search College" onChange={event =>{setSearchVal(event.target.value)}}></input>
     {collegeList.filter((val)=>{
         if(searchVal==""){
             return val;
         }else if (val.Name_of_College.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())){
             return val;
         }
     }).map((val)=>{
        return <div className="clgListDiv" > <p>
          College Name: {val.Name_of_College} <br></br>
          </p>
          </div>
          })}
   </div> 
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice in React:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [searchVal, setSearchVal] = useState("");
  //getting values from DB
  const content = collegeList
    .filter((val) => {
      if (searchVal == "") {
        return val;
      } else if (
        val.Name_of_College.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        return val;
      }
    })
    .map((val) => {
      return (
        <div className="clgListDiv">
          <p>
            College Name: {val.Name_of_College} <br></br>
          </p>
        </div>
      );
    });
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search College"
        onChange={(event) => {
          setSearchVal(event.target.value);
        }}
      ></input>
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Other than moving some code how does this address the issue OP has with CSS not being applied? Seems you are answering an unrelated question. There is nothing inherently incorrect with filtering and mapping JSX *in the return*. If you care about it then at least also point out that `.filter` should be returning a boolean value instead of the iterated element` or undefined.